# Do double quotes (") act like field delimiters or as an escape character, or both in CSV files?

Tags: python, csv, parsing

I've read that the delimiter of a CSV is the comma (,) and the escape character is the double quotes (").  What I don't understand is why or how double quotes (") are used to also preserve spaces in field values...What I mean is this claim: "CSV files use double-quote marks to delimit field values that have spaces, so a value like Santa Claus gets saved as “Santa Claus”".  Why would the space not be preserved?  Also, if double quotes (") is the escape character, how is the S in "Santa Clause" not escaped?  What about the comma that will inevitably come after "Santa Clause"?  Wouldn't that be escaped by the double quotes after the e in Clause?  Obviously not... because it doesn't get escaped and acts as a delimiter as it is supposed to when parsed.  And so my question is essentially investigating the role of double quotes (") in CSV files, because it seems like it's two fold (Almost acting like a delimiter and an escape character), and yet I cannot find an explanation of this anywhere.  Thanks in advance.

This is my first question, so I'm sorry if this isn't quite the right place for a question that doesn't deal with code itself, but I am currently dealing with parsing lots of csv files in python that are given in text format, where these double quotes do not surround every field value.  I was using the split() method to.. well.. to split the string up by line, and then by values, but then I realized I needed to account for escape characters and that's when I started to think hard about how a CSV file works.  I thought I understood the concept of escape characters in general, and still think I do, but observing the role(s) double quotes play in CSVs, I realized I was missing some kind of intuition.   Just hoping for some clarity.

Comment: I wouldn't call double-quote an escape character.  Where did you read that?

Comment: @JohnGordon If you google "What is the escape character for CSV" The immediate answer is double quotes.  And they also do act as escape characters in some kind of way because  you escape double quotes and commas within field values  by putting a double quote before them.  I guess they have some escape behavior?  What would you call the double quote in the context of a csv file? What role does it play?  Because like I said it seems like it almost plays two separate roles.

Comment: When I think of an "escape character", I think of something that can occur _singly_, and grants a special meaning to the _next single character_.  i.e. something like `\n` means "carriage return", not literally "backslash n".  But in a csv file, quotes should be used in _pairs_, and they confer special meaning to _all the characters in between_, typically to not treat commas inside the quotes as column separators.

Comment: So, I guess double quotes are kinda-sorta an escape character?

Comment: @JohnGordon Haha I'm honestly trying to understand how csvs work at large, and I'm coming to understand it is more of a convention than a standard.  That being said, I'm starting to shed light on how it *usually* works.  Getting into encoding and decoding and unicode now as well.  Also your comment of escape characters is starting to make me think differently about how those are conceptualized (Don't think I had the best intuition at first), so I appreciate you chiming in to help!

Answer (score 0):

Consider what happens when you want a string with a comma as a field in your row. You would need some sort of way to let the csv parser that this is not a parsing comma, but it is a 'data comma', so you need to denote it in some sort of special form. usually this is done by enclosing the field with a comma in double quotes. From the RFC https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180:

> 4. Within the header and each record, there may be one or more
>    fields, separated by commas.  Each line should contain the same
>    number of fields throughout the file.  Spaces are considered part
>    of a field and should not be ignored.  The last field in the
>    record must not be followed by a comma.  For example:
>
>    aaa,bbb,ccc
> 5. Each field may or may not be enclosed in double quotes (however
>    some programs, such as Microsoft Excel, do not use double quotes
>    at all).  If fields are not enclosed with double quotes, then
>    double quotes may not appear inside the fields.  For example:
>
>    "aaa","bbb","ccc" CRLF
>    zzz,yyy,xxx
> 6. Fields containing line breaks (CRLF), double quotes, and commas
>    should be enclosed in double-quotes.  For example:
>
>    "aaa","b CRLF
>    bb","ccc" CRLF
>    zzz,yyy,xxx
> 7. If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote
>    appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with
>    another double quote.  For example: